# Nested For Next loop issue. Graph using every member of results

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, for-loop, devexpress

I have 2 `For Next` loops that I use to send the results to a `Chart`. However, series lines are muddled.

I understand the problem but I couldn't find a solution. The `Chart` shows all points, but I need to match the first iterated points together, second iterated points together...etc.

Here is the code:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim n as integer
Dim speed as decimal
Dim horsepower as decimal

For i=1 to 30 Step 2
    For n=1 to 20 Step 1

        Dim power as label=CType(GroupBox1.Controls("Label"&n),Label)

        Dim txt as textbox=CType(Tabcontrolpanel1.Controls("TextBox"&i),Textbox)

        horsepower=Val(power.text)*3.14

        speed=Val(txt.Text)*3*5

        ChartControl1.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New Seriespoint(horsepower, speed)

    Next

Next
```

I need to draw (x,y) (horsepower1,speed1),(horsepower2,speed2)...etc. Not (horsepower1,speed2), (horsepower1,speed3)

Comment: Your question is unclear... what do you mean by "first iterated points"

Comment: For example; I need to draw chart like (1,1),(2,2) not (1,2)(1,3)(1,4)

Comment: They can not all match since you have 15 speed textbox and 20 horsepower label.

Comment: But how do you do that when you have different loop sizes...

Comment: IF it was "square" then you only need one loop....

Comment: Maybe you dont understand what I mean; Just forget above For nested loop as example; For i=1 to=3, For n=1 to=3 , outocome will be (1,1),(1,2)(1,3),  (2,1)(2,2)(2,3).....etc. I would like to have (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)

Comment: See answer 1 ... you only should be using one loop and calculating the other index.

Comment: trevor , thank you very much, What about if label start label90 etc, what I am going to do, I can not use 1 for loop

Answer (score 1):

They can not all match since you have 15 speed textbox and 20 horsepower label. But if you want to do it with the first 15, you'll have to do it with one loop.

```
For i=1 to 15

   Dim power as label=CType(GroupBox1.Controls("Label"&i),Label)
   Dim txt as textbox=CType(Tabcontrolpanel1.Controls("TextBox"&(i*2-1)),Textbox)

   horsepower=Val(power.text)*3.14
   speed=Val(txt.Text)*3*5

   ChartControl1.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New Seriespoint(horsepower, speed)

Next
```

If you have different starting index, you'll have to keep it in a variable.

```
' First matching index
Dim labelIndex As Integer = 1
Dim textboxIndex As Integer = 1

For i=1 to 15

   Dim power as label=CType(GroupBox1.Controls("Label"&labelIndex),Label)
   Dim txt as textbox=CType(Tabcontrolpanel1.Controls("TextBox"&textboxIndex),Textbox)

   horsepower=Val(power.text)*3.14
   speed=Val(txt.Text)*3*5

   ChartControl1.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New Seriespoint(horsepower, speed)

   ' Go to the next matching index
   labelIndex += 1
   textboxIndex += 2
Next
```

Comment: What about if label start label90 etc, what I am going to do, I can not use 1 for loop

Comment: @Emrah I added an other part to the answer. You would have to initialize labelIndex to 90. If your label are all over the place, then you'll need to find an other way of matching them. Having them in the same panel, or row of a datagrid, or having tags, ... The fact that you have 90 labels named label{x} is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much the_lotus muchthe, I will try it.

Comment: COuld you please have a look answer below and help me?